# Copy image file in a path to SQL Server (using Asp.net, vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, image, path

I am very new to asp.net programming. I have an Excel workbook containing locations of image files for e.g. `C:\Users\Suresh\Desktop\DWG\images (0).jpg` in column C (there are more than 50 image paths in column C).

I am looking for a method to copy these image files from the above path and store them in a SQL Server database table.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance,
Suresh.

**Reposting my question here.. please anyone help me..**

I have created a sub, which receives excel cell content, it extracts all image paths and image ids, containing in the passing string, store them in variables like imgPath, imgID respectively, and then insert in to the database. i have tried to assign the image path to image2.ImageUrl property, but dont know how to convert it and save in to database.

*(Image path and image id are located in between #IMGSTART" and "#IMGEND#" tags in the passing string)*

My database fields are defined like this

[RowID]     INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,

[ProjectID] VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,

[ImageID]   VARCHAR (50)    NULL,

[Image]     VARBINARY (MAX) NULL

Private Sub ExtractImgLinks_SaveToDB(qStr As String)

```
Dim Pos As Integer = InStr(1, qStr.ToUpper(), "#IMGSTART")
Dim tmpStr As String = Mid(qStr, Pos, (qStr.Length() - Pos))
Dim Conn1 As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CreateUserConnectionString").ConnectionString)
Conn1.Open()
Do While Pos > 0
    Dim imgID As String = Mid(tmpStr, 10, 3)
    Dim imgPath As String = Mid(tmpStr, 14, (InStr(1, tmpStr.ToUpper(), "#IMGEND#") - 14))

    Image2.ImageUrl = imgPath

    ### need help here to convert image to VARBINARY ###

    'insert image to database
    Dim QryInsertStr As String = "insert into tbl_Result_Images (ProjectID, ImageID, Image) " & _
                                "values (@ProjectID, @ImageID, @Image)"
    Dim com As New SqlCommand(QryInsertStr, Conn1)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", Session("ProjID").ToString())
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageID", imgID)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", ????)
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    tmpStr = Right(tmpStr, Len(tmpStr) - (InStr(1, tmpStr.ToUpper(), "#IMGEND#") + 8))
    Pos = InStr(1, tmpStr.ToUpper(), "#IMGSTART")
Loop
Conn1.Close()
```

End Sub

Please suggest me a solution. Thanks Suresh.

Comment: i have given my code in below answer space. please go through it and help me.. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnect)
con.Open()
Using com As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO myTable (imagePath) VALUES (@IM)", con)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IM", "C:\My Images\the name of the image.jpg")
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i need to store the actual image files from the location mentioned in the excel file instead of path. The path refers to the actual file locations in my hard drive. instead  of using fileupload control, how can i save the files directly from my hard drive using a known path like "C:\My Images\the name of the image.jpg". I appreciate any clues for solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For each image try:

- Read the file location from the spreadsheet.
- Load the image from that location into an Image or Bitmap object.
- Convert the object to Base64 (ImageToBase64(pImage)).
- Save the Base64 object to the database table.

If you need to know how to do any of these just ask...

As an example:

```
Dim Conn1 As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CreateUserConnectionString").ConnectionString)

    Dim imgID As Integer = 1
    Dim imagePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), "MyImage.bmp")

    Dim imageFile As New IO.FileStream(imagePath, IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim imageSize As Integer = CInt(imageFile.Length)
    Dim imageByteArray(imageSize - 1) As Byte
    imageFile.Read(imageByteArray, 0, imageSize)

    'Insert image into database
    Dim QryInsertStr As String = "INSERT INTO ImageTable (Id, ImageColumn) VALUES (@IdData, @ImageData)"
    Conn1.Open()
    Dim com As New SqlCommand(QryInsertStr, Conn1)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdData", imgID)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageData", imageByteArray)
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Conn1.Close()
```

And repeat for all of your image data.

Comment: i need more explanation on your logic. my image datatype is VARBINARY(MAX)  in sql database. i have given my code in the below answer space, and request you to take a look. thanks.